# How can I group by date and save for loop output into new variable?

Tags: r, for-loop, group-by

I am trying to loop through a csv file that has first.name (IDs) of each person and the date each person completed a task. Before I analyze the tasks I am trying to group each date by a weekly value (week 1 being day 1:7 per person, week 2,3 etc) each person started on a different date and continues for an average of 30-40 days (some with missing days in between). I need the weeks to start based on the unique first date of each person's data until the end date.

My raw data looks like this:

```
  ï..first.name Last.Name User.ID       Date
1          5006    'G103'   23412 2018-05-07  
2          5006    'G103'   23412 2018-05-08   
3          5006    'G103'   23412 2018-05-09  
4          5007    'G104'   23413 2018-05-07
5          5007    'G104'   23413 2018-05-10  
6          5006    'G103'   23412 2018-05-15   
7          5008    'G105'   23414 2018-05-07  
8          5007    'G104'   23413 2018-05-19
```

My code:

```
outputWeek = matrix()  #empty matrix

for(x in 1:length(unique(Raw_whoop$ï..first.name))){ #1 through each unique ID
  whoopName = as.character(unique(Raw_whoop$ï..first.name)[x]) #get ID name
  dvec = as.Date(Raw_whoop$Date[Raw_whoop$ï..first.name == whoopName]) #get dates associated with that name
  dweek = as.numeric(dvec-dvec[1]) %/% 7 # group those dates into weeks

  outputWeek[x] = dweek #store the dates in new variable that I can later append to the csv file as a new column. **but this doesn't work**
```

everything works except my last line when I try to troubleshoot. I have tried c/rbind instead of [x] and I keep getting various errors.

I would like my output to look something like:

```
 ï..first.name Last.Name User.ID       Date  Week #
1          5006    'G103'   23412 2018-05-07  0 
2          5006    'G103'   23412 2018-05-08  0  
3          5006    'G103'   23412 2018-05-09  0
4          5007    'G104'   23413 2018-05-07  0
5          5007    'G104'   23413 2018-05-10  0
6          5006    'G103'   23412 2018-05-15  1 
7          5008    'G105'   23414 2018-05-07  0
8          5007    'G104'   23413 2018-05-19  1
```

Ideally I can just have a new variable "week#" in one column and later append/paste the values along side the CSV file when sorted by ID.

Thanks

Comment: Please post reproducible data in a copy&paste-able format; screenshots of your data are never a good idea; use `dput` instead. Also include your expected output; I don't think you need a `for` loop here, as all operations inside your `for` loop are already vectorised.

Comment: thanks I have updated the format but I am not sure what I can do if not a for loop to go through the 45 IDs? Are you suggesting an apply function?

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. Your sample data has 8 rows; your expected output has >8 entries. I also struggle to make sense of your problem statement; this seems like a job for `tapply` or `ave` but hard to say without reproducible data and output.

Comment: This is still not clear @shai73; why is `Week# = 1` for row 6? The date (`2018-05-15`) is 5 days *after* the first date (`2018-05-07`) so it should still be the same week. And again, there is *definitely* no need for an explicit `for` loop here.

Comment: @MauritsEvers The dates between the sample data and expected output are different (as in reality I have 2000 rows). I edited the data to be the same now. For the expected output Row 6 is ID(5006) which is May 15th but ID(5006) starts on May 7th (row 1). Those should be 8 days (and therefore 1 week) apart. Do you have a suggestion of how to apply an alternative to the for loop?

Comment: It *really* doesn't help if you change your input data. The date for row 6 was `2018-05-12` before, now it's `2018-05-15`. You also changed the date for row 8!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a `for` loop; this is a simple case for integer division using `%/%`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(User.ID) %>%
    mutate(week_no = as.integer(as.Date(Date) - first(as.Date(Date))) %/% 7) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 8 x 5
#  ï..first.name Last.Name User.ID Date       week_no
#          <int> <fct>       <int> <fct>        <dbl>
#1          5006 G103        23412 2018-05-07       0
#2          5006 G103        23412 2018-05-08       0
#3          5006 G103        23412 2018-05-09       0
#4          5007 G104        23413 2018-05-07       0
#5          5007 G104        23413 2018-05-10       0
#6          5006 G103        23412 2018-05-15       1
#7          5008 G105        23414 2018-05-07       0
#8          5007 G104        23413 2018-05-19       1
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "  ï..first.name Last.Name User.ID       Date
1          5006    'G103'   23412 2018-05-07
2          5006    'G103'   23412 2018-05-08
3          5006    'G103'   23412 2018-05-09
4          5007    'G104'   23413 2018-05-07
5          5007    'G104'   23413 2018-05-10
6          5006    'G103'   23412 2018-05-15
7          5008    'G105'   23414 2018-05-07
8          5007    'G104'   23413 2018-05-19", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered I can "solve" this by assigning outputWeek variable before the for loop into a list instead of a matrix. However, I am not sure this method is the most efficient so any help is appreciated.